# Tilting Octahedra of Perovskite structures in structure file

Tags: crystallography, perovskites

Perovskite materials form as a combination of $\ce{BX_6}$ octahdera along with A cation. Some perovskites display tilted octahedras. I am currently trying to run calculations for different tilted versions, but how do I tilt only one small part of a whole cif file.

Assume that I have to the modification shown below. I know I can not use VESTA, are there any software out there capable of doing this?

[image]

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you made any progress on this over the last 7 months? Please update us!